# What is the expected behavior when both `position: absolute` and `float: left` is used?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float, css-position

Using `position: absolute` and `float:left` together looks like a bit confusing and even absurd, because `position: absolute` will not affect the position of sibling elements while `float:left` will affect the position of sibling **float** elements.

However,  using them together is allowed in CSS, so what is the expected behavior? I'm not quite sure what will happen when both of them is used as it is not described in the MDN document (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

Does anyone have any ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: You should build some test cases and sort it out.  Using them together seems completely wrong - I assume that position: absolute will "override" the effect on siblings, and it will cause the element to essentially not take "space" with respect to position of other elements on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is discussed in CSS2 specification (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo):

> Otherwise, if
>   'position' has the value 'absolute' or 'fixed', the box is absolutely
>   positioned, the computed value of 'float' is 'none', and display is
>   set according to the table below. The position of the box will be
>   determined by the 'top', 'right', 'bottom' and 'left' properties and
>   the box's containing block.

So the conclusion is that `float` is set to `none` compulsively when `position` has the value `absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `float:left;` to an `absolute` positioned element obviously dosen't add any behavioural change of the element. Same is the case with most of the `display` properties..For example, adding `display:inline;` dosen't cause to lose its dimension.

Nor does it has shows any connection with an adjacent floated element.

```css
.box{
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;  
}
.box1{
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
```

But when the `float` of the adjacent element is removed, the absolutely positioned element is positioned below it.

```css
.box{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;  
}
.box1{
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
```